# Обработка четных строк в текстовом файле

Tags: linux, bash

В одном из текстовых файлов во всех чётных строках перенести слова задом наперед (Раз два три -> три два Раз). Использовать не более одного вспомогательного файла.
Я нашел регулярку:
sed -i 'n;s/(\w+)\W*(.+)/\2 \1/' file.txt,
которая перемещает первое слово в конец строки, но не могу сообразить как ее переписать под себя.

Answer (score 0):

awk подойдет?

```
awk '{if (NR%2==0) {for(i=NF; i>0; i--) printf("%s ",$i); print "";} else print}'
```

лишний пробел только в конце строки остается.